# How can I use and access an SQLite DB using PHP and Wamp Server?

Tags: php, database, windows, sqlite, pdo

I know PHP 5 already supports SQLite but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I followed the instructions from [*SQLite tutorial: Getting started*](http://www.scriptol.com/sql/sqlite-getting-started.php). I also made sure that the following are not commented out from php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll 
extension=php_sqlite.dll.
```

But when I open the PHP file from localhost using Firefox, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found.

I'm on Windows by the way, if that info matters.

What may be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the class `SQLiteDatabase` is from the extension `sqlite` rather `pdo_sqlite`. So you could enable the `sqlite` extension, or use PDO instead:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('sqlite:c:/mydb.sq3');
$conn->exec('some sql query');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I was able to get past opening the db because now the errors pertain to the query! Now I just have to learn the syntax and all! Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

On Windows you need to have the following set in your ini:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

I recommend you read [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Class `SQLiteDatabase` is an object from [sqlite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) library, which support was dropped in PHP 5.4, but on various systems and configuration could be disabled in an earlier releases, as this library was long time marked as *going to be deprecated*.

Library `php_sqlite.dll` (Windows) or `php_sqlite.so` (Linux) is no longer supported in newer versions of PHP and was replaced with `php_sqlite3.dll` or `php_sqlite3.so` respectively.

You can:

1. Try to find `php_sqlite.dll` (`php_sqlite.so`) somewhere in the Internet. Links like [this](http://www.dlldll.com/php_sqlite.dll_download.html) or [this](http://originaldll.com/file/php_sqlite.dll/30736.html) may be helpful for you. However, you'll have to carefully match old SQLite library file to your PHP's platform (`x64` or `x86`), build engine (`VC6`, `VC9` or `VC11`), version (`5.x`) and type (`TS` for *thread safe* or `NTS` for *non-thread safe*). This might be a hard task.
2. Leave `php_sqlite.dll` (`SQLiteDatabase`) behind and ship toward new `php_sqlite3.dll` (`SQLite3` object). You have to first use a tool like [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/?act=download) to convert your database file from 2.1 to 3.0 (size can be lowered by even a half) and then carefully compare [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) and [SQLite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) PHP manual pages to change necessary objects and functions call.

If option *two*, note that this shouldn't be a hard work, as changes aren't that big. For example, what I've learned so far:

- `SQLiteDatabase` -> `SQLite3`,
- `SQLiteDatabase::unbufferedQuery` -> `SQLite3::query`,
- `SQLiteResult::fetchAll(SQLITE_*)` -> `SQLite3Result::fetchArray(SQLITE3_*)` etc.

As for fetching, in old [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) we had:

```
$rowsIMEI = $db->unbufferedQuery($imeiSQL)->fetchAll(SQLITE_ASSOC);

foreach($rowsIMEI as $r)
{
    ...
}
```

While, in new [SQLite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) we should:

```
$rowsIMEI = $db->query($imeiSQL);

while($r = $rowsIMEI->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    ...
}
```

Other changes requires similar amount of work, so this shouldn't be a life-time process.

I, of course, strongly advice anyone to go forward and choose *second* option. Progress is in most cases the better one of two available options.